# SPF failure I don't understand with mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp, spf

**In a nutshell**

I've configured a SPF policy on my domain but I receive a dmarc report with an failure. I don't understand why there is this failure.

**More context**

I've configured the following spf policy for my domain `zerowasteparis.fr`: `v=spf1 include:spf.infomaniak.ch include:servers.mcsv.net include:_spf.google.com ~all`. I see that `servers.mcsv.net` resolves to `v=spf1 ip4:205.201.128.0/20 ip4:198.2.128.0/18 ip4:148.105.8.0/21 ?all`
(I also configured a dkim policy which seems to work just fine).

I don't understand why I received a dmarc report which contains in particular:

```
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>198.2.190.251</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>zerowasteparis.fr</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>automations.mcsv.net</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>k1</selector>
      </dkim>
      <dkim>
        <domain>zerowasteparis.fr</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>k1</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>mail251.suw12.mcsv.net</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
```

I don't understand why it contains the line `<spf>fail</spf>`.

**Why I'm puzzled**

- From a tech engineering point of view, if I'm not mistaken
  `198.2.190.251` is in the range `ip4:198.2.128.0/18` (since it
  represents the range `198.2.128.0` to `198.2.191.255`)
- From a social engineering point of view it would mean that [mailchimp spf doc](https://mailchimp.com/help/set-up-custom-domain-authentication-dkim-and-spf/) is incorrect, but since their job is to send email, I'm having
  trouble believing it.

Long story short: I don't understand why I see this failure in this report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mailchimp (like number of other well known ESPs) is designed in a way to use their own email address in MailFrom (**RFC5321.MailFrom**). The main reason behind this is to handle bounces of campaign emails.

SPF validation performs check if Source/Sender IP is included in SPF record of [domain mentioned in MailFrom](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-1.1.3) field.

1. **domain** tag in XML file contains domain retrieved from message header's **smtp.mailfrom**: *mail251.suw12.mcsv.net*
2. **source_ip** tag: *198.2.190.251*
3. The [SPF record defined for mail251.suw12.mcsv.net](https://easydmarc.com/tools/spf/mail251.suw12.mcsv.net) domain: *v=spf1 ip4:198.2.190.251 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all*, i.e sending IP is covered with SPF.

That is why have SPF=pass in **auth_results** section.

```
  <spf>
    <domain>mail251.suw12.mcsv.net</domain>
    <result>pass</result>
  </spf>
```

Unlike SPF, DMARC validation perform the check if [domain mentioned in From](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-5) field (**RFC5322.From**) matches / aligned with domain mentioned in MailFrom (**RFC5321.MailFrom**)

1. rDNS/PTR of 198.2.190.251 from **source_ip** tag: *mail251.suw12.mcsv.net*
2. Domain mentioned in **header_from** tag: *zerowasteparis.fr*
3. Thus, domain in RFC5322.From (zerowasteparis.fr) does not match / not aligned with domain in RFC5321.MailFrom (mcsv.net)

That is why you get SPF=fail in **policy_evaluated** section.

```
  <policy_evaluated>
    <disposition>none</disposition>
    <dkim>pass</dkim>
    <spf>fail</spf>
  </policy_evaluated>
</row>
<identifiers>
  <header_from>zerowasteparis.fr</header_from>
</identifiers>
```

Apart of above explanation, I would suggest you deploy one of [DMARC Analytics and Implementation solutions](https://dmarc.org/resources/products-and-services/), listed on DMARC.org website, e.g. [EasyDMARC](https://easydmarc.com/tools).